# replace a specific character in a string using string index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Ive tried using .replace() but when I use an index to define the character being replaced, it replaces all of the characters that are the same as the one being indexed as shown here:

```
string = "cool"
print(string.replace(string[1], "u"))
```

if returns:

```
"cuul"
```

But I just want the specific character which the index of string[1] to be replaced, for example, I want it to work as such:

```
string = "cool"
print(substitute(string[1],"u")
```

such that it prints:

```
"cuol"
```

Comment: I would turn the string into a list, replace the character, and turn it back into a string again, but I don't know whether that is what you are looking for. ```string = list(string); string[1] = "u"; string = "".join(string)```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```py
stirng1 = "cool"
list1 = list(string1)
list1[1] = "u"
print("".join(list1))
```

When executed :

```py
>>>cuol
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is search for `string[1]` which is `o` and replace all instances of `o` with `u`.

```
string = "cool"
print(string.replace(string[1], "u"))
# cuul
```

The issue is that string objects are `immutable`, so you will just have to create a new string that includes the value at the desired index.

```
index = 1
char = 'u'

print(string[:index] + char + string[index+1:])
#cuol
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def substitute(string,index,char):
    strlist = list(string)
    strlist[index] = char
    return ''.join(strlist)
```

Comment: How is this answer different from previously posted answer?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Didn't see any other posts when I started typing. I'm typing on my phone so I type a little slow.

Comment: all good. please try to update the page before posting to avoid redundant answers. thanks!